# Apply style to div inside the nth in the Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

**Here is my** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2jtos5x/)

Here i need to apply the style to the value "Test" which is under the nth child of given div.

Note i should not use class as i am using flexigrid.

How can i do this ?

**Here is my Style**

```
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
th:nth-child(2) {
    background : red !important;
}
```

Comment: When you say you want to apply style to the value `Test` do you mean the containing `div`, the `th`, or the column it's in? Please be more accurate in your questions.

Comment: Do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/s6ssbghL/)? `th:nth-child(2) div {background : red !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is indeed kinda vague.
But you dont need a class to style this datatable.

#### ROW STYLE

`tr:nth-child(2) {
    background : red !important;
}`

#### COLUMN STYLE

`td:nth-child(2) {
    background : red !important;
}`

#### HEADING STYLE

`th:nth-child(2) {
    background : red !important;
}`

Comment: Don't used to !important   http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
th:nth-child(2) div {
    background : red;
}
```